# No Such Module FacebookLogin in ios swift 3

Tags: ios

I am doing facebook login in iOS(swift) . I have already done all the stuff related to pod install carefully, but while importing 'FacebookLogin' I am getting error like "No Such Module FacebookLogin".

I had gone through all the possible options, but I couldn't get a satisfactory solution yet. So , someone please tell me why I am facing this kind of problem and what is the exact solution can be?

[Code error screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngDSw.png)

Comment: did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out carefully that you opened `xcworkspace` file instead of `ixcodeproj` file. In `xcodeproj` file your pods will not be available.

**UPDATE:**
Try to delete pod directory in your workspace, then `clean` + `clean build folder` + `delete derived data`, then run `pod install` again and `build`. Must work if you configurated your podfile correctly.

Comment: yes i have opened xcworkspace file but still getting that error

Comment: `target 'FBLoginDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'

  # Pods for FBLoginDemo

  target 'FBLoginDemoTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end`

Answer (score 0):

Add to podfile:

`pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
 pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
 pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'`

Add in your file:

```
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

Comment: I have done all the stuff related to pod installation